# Magento. How I Know if an Attribute is Used in Product Listing or not?

Tags: magento, attributes

I need to know what attributes are "Used in Product Listing" checked as YES, but don't find any function, like $attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()

In fact, I don't know how to get option values from 'Frontend Properties' of attributes (Use in Quick Search, Use in Advanced Search, ...)

My code is somthing like this:

```
<?php $attributes = $_product->getAttributes();             
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->getIsUsedInProductListing()) {
                       echo $attribute->getStoreLabel();
                    }
            }
    ?>
```

getIsUsedInProductListing() don't exist ;-)

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is quite easy to do.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); // Or, use your product
$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);

foreach ($attributes as $attribute){
     var_dump($attribute); // You will be able to see all of the attribute settings here.

     if ($attribute->getUsedInProductListing()) {
          // Do cool things here.
     }

     if ($attribute->getIsHtmlAllowedOnFront()) {
          // Do cool things here.
     }

     if ($attribute->getIsVisibleInAdvancedSearch()) {
          // Do cool things here.
     }

     if ($attribute->getUsedForSortBy()) {
          // Do cool things here.
     }
}
```

Comment: Oh man !!! Thank you !!!

Only a little correction (at least for me):

$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);